Performance Issues with Large Dataset for Frequent Itemsets Mining
I’m working on a data mining project, specifically focusing on mining frequent itemsets. My dataset contains 175 unique items and 1400 transactions, but I’m encountering significant performance issues when using algorithms like Apriori and FP-Growth. The runtime is extremely long, and I’m unsure how to optimize this process.
I’ve tried adjusting the minimum support threshold, but the execution times are still unacceptably high. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can improve the efficiency in this case? Are there alternative algorithms that might perform better with large datasets?
